# Combine items from different rows in database and display them in one row on listview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I have items in a database.  The columns are ID, Region, and Report.  I display all these in an asp listview.  I need combine each of these items and display them in one row for each id.  So for example if ID = testuser  Regions = 1, 2  Reports = A, B

Right now the list displays something like this:

testuser | 1 | A

testuser | 1 | B

testuser | 2 | A

testuser | 2 | B

I want it to be:

testuser | 1,2  | A,B

Here is the front end:

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="tableRow">
            <td class="value">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCWSID" Text='<%# Eval("CwsId") %>'></asp:Label>

            </td>
            <td class="value">
                <asp:Label ID="lblRegion" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Regions") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="value" style="width: 70px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblReport" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Reports") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="value" style="width: 50px">
             <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/Images/edit-icon.png"
                    OnCommand="btnEdit_User" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CWSID") %>' Height="20px"
                    Width="20px" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/Images/remove-icon.png"
                    OnCommand="btnDelete_User" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CWSID") %>' Height="20px"
                    Width="20px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Here is the backend:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Add a user to the list and then rebind
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void lbSaveUser_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {


        List<string> selectedRegions = RegionsCheckBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        .Where(li => li.Selected)
        .Select(li => li.Value)
        .ToList();

        List<string> selectedReports = ReportsCheckBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        .Where(li => li.Selected)
        .Select(li => li.Value)
        .ToList();

        try
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCWSID.Text))
            {
                this.lblError.Text = "Please enter a valid CWS ID";
                return;
            }

            if (Common.GetUserCwsId() == txtCWSID.Text.Trim())
            {
                this.lblError.Text = "It would not be a good idea to block yourself from the site";
                return;
            }

            ReportPermissionsFactory.DeleteReportPermissionUser(txtCWSID.Text, Common.GetConnectionString());
            foreach (string Region in selectedRegions)
            {
                foreach (string Report in selectedReports)
                {
                    ReportPermissionsFactory.InsUpdReportPermissions(txtCWSID.Text.Trim(),Region, Report, Common.GetConnectionString());
                }
            }
            txtCWSID.Text = String.Empty; 

            BindList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.HandleException(Common.GetUserCwsId(), Projects.GlobalSizingTool, "ReportPermissionsUsers", "lbAddUser_Click", ex, Common.GetConnectionString());
            this.lblError.Text = "There was an error completing your request.  Please try again.";
        }
    }
```

Here is how the data gets loaded:

```
internal static List<ReportPermissions> LoadData(string connectionString, bool refresh = false)
    {
        string cacheItem = "ReportPermissionsFactory";
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

        if (refresh)
        {
            cache.Remove(cacheItem);
        }

        List<ReportPermissions> l = cache[cacheItem] as List<ReportPermissions>;

        if (l == null || l.Count == 0)
        {
            l = new List<ReportPermissions>();
            Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(connectionString);
            DbCommand wrapper = db.GetStoredProcCommand("usp_GetReportPermissionsUsers");
            IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(wrapper);

            using (wrapper)
            {
                using (reader)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        ReportPermissions obj = new ReportPermissions();
                        obj.CwsId= SizingDBLayer.Utilities.GetDBFieldString(reader["CwsId"]);
                        obj.Regions = SizingDBLayer.Utilities.GetDBFieldString(reader["RegionCode"]);
                        obj.Reports = SizingDBLayer.Utilities.GetDBFieldString(reader["Reports"]);
                        l.Add(obj);
                    }
                }
            }
            cache.Add(cacheItem, l, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)));
        }
        return l;
    }
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, it doesn't look like the method you posted is relevant to this question. Post the `BindList` method.

Comment: @DaveZych Hey, I've added the code that BindList gets its info from .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how this ended up working:

```
 List<ReportPermissions> finalizedItems = new List<ReportPermissions>();

            foreach (ReportPermissions rp in l)
            {
                //Check to see if record for this user exists
                if (!finalizedItems.Any(x => x.CwsId == rp.CwsId))
                {
                    // if it doesn't exist, get it
                    ReportPermissions perm = new ReportPermissions();
                    perm.CwsId = rp.CwsId;

                    perm.Reports = string.Join(",", l.Where(x => x.CwsId == rp.CwsId).Select(x => x.Reports).Distinct());
                    perm.Regions = string.Join(",", l.Where(x => x.CwsId == rp.CwsId).Select(x => x.Regions).Distinct());
                    finalizedItems.Add(perm);
                }
            }

            l= finalizedItems;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new class (or even an anonymous object) that holds the Id along with a CSV of the `Regions` and `Reports`. Get the data in the same way you're doing, but group it by the `CwsId` and build up a new list of the new class. Something like:

```
public class ReportPermissionsById
{
    public int CwsId { get; set; }
    public string Regions { get; set; }
    public string Reports { get; set; }
}

public void BindList()
{
    var list = LoadData(connString);
    var reportPermissionsById = list
       .GroupBy(r => r.CwsId)
       .Select(r =>
            new ReportPermissionsById
            {
                 CwsId = r.Key,
                 Regions = string.Join(",", r.Select(d => d.Regions)),
                 Reports = string.Join(",", r.Select(d => d.Reports)),
            }
        );

   //Use reportPermissionsById to bind your ListView
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this.  I posted the code that worked.